# Scala - parse JSON data from API with ScalaJson Play Framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework

First I have implemented a method to build a `Map[Double, String]` from a csv file. The map contains (k,v) of saleId, saleType. 
Here is how I've implemented this:

```
val stream : InputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/sales.csv")
  val lines: Iterator[String] = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(stream).getLines
  val map: Map[Double, String] = lines
    .map(_.split(","))
    .map(line => (line(0).toDouble, line(1).toString))
    .toMap
```

Now I want to go further and get data for building a map with data from API. With the same k,v (saleId, saleType). Json returned by API contains this data as fields.

Json look like this:

```
   [{ 
    "saleId": 1234, 
    "name": "New name", 
    "saleType": "New Type"
    }, 
    { 
    "saleId": 2345, 
    "name": "New name1", 
    "saleType": "New Type1" 
   }]
```

So I tried the approach using ScalaJson Play Framework. Since I only need two fields from JSON I decided to use a case class `SalesData`.

```
object SalesProcessor {
    case class SalesData(saleId: Int, saleType: String)
    implicit val of: Reads[SalesData] = reads[SalesData]

      val rawJson: String = Source.fromURL("https://mytest.com/api/sales.json").mkString
      val salesJson: JsValue = Json.parse(rawJson)
      val salesData: SalesData = salesJson.as[SalesData]

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println(salesData.saleId)
    }
```

When I run the above code I'm getting the following error:

`play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsobject),WrappedArray())))))`

**UPD:** After I've used a solution proposed by **`tea-addict`** it started failing with the following error:

```
JsResultException(errors:List((/saleId,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray()))), (/saleType,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray())))))
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the `sales.json` file

Comment: @Seraf added Json example to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read specific fields and create your `SalesData` like this.

Sales.json

```
[{ 
  "saleId": 1234, 
  "name": "New name", 
  "saleType": "New Type"
}, 
{ 
  "saleId": 2345, 
  "name": "New name1", 
  "saleType": "New Type1" 
 }]
```

Code

```
object SalesProcessor {
    case class SalesData(saleId: Int, saleType: String)
    implicit val saleReads: Reads[SalesData] = (
        (JsPath \ "saleId").read[Int] and
        (JsPath \ "saleType").read[String]
    ) (SalesData.apply _)

    val rawJson: String = Source.fromURL("https://mytest.com/api/sales.json").mkString
    val salesJson: JsValue = Json.parse(rawJson)
    val salesData: List[SalesData] = salesJson.as[List[SalesData]]

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println(salesData(0).saleId)
    }
}
```

Comment: I need only two fields from json file: saleId and saleType. Sorry for misrepresenting the json file, it actually has the same field names as the case class

Comment: Still getting `JsResultException(errors:List((/saleId,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray()))), (/saleType,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray())))))` . Could it be caused by the json structure (objects wrapped into array)? I've updated my post with the valid example of json

Comment: val salesData: List[SalesData] = salesJson.as[List[SalesData]]

Comment: I've changed to List[SalesData] as you suggested above. And called `salesData.foreach(sale => println(sale.saleId + " " + sale.saleType))`. Now getting JsonValidationErrors:  `((1234)/saleId,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsnumber),WrappedArray()))), ((2345)/saleId,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsnumber),WrappedArray())))` ..... etc

Comment: I think the problem is actually your `"saleId": 1234, ` is `"saleId": "1234" `. It expects a number but your json file has it as string, can you check it again :)

Comment: Thank you soo much! You really helped me to reevaluate my solution and to look at the problem from different sides.